# How to create or filter an object array with defined key and value from an object array in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, object

How can I get or filter an object array from an old or input object array with only defined keys and values. that is a little bit abstract. I can show an example:

the old object array looks like this:

```
[{
  op:AND
  id:0
  level: 0
  predicates: [{
    op: EQ
    field: abc,
    id:1.1
    level: 1
  }, {
    op "OR"
    id:1.2
    level: 1
    predicates: [{
      op: NEQ
      id:2.1
      level: 2
      field: 12312
    },
    {
      op: AND
      id: 2.2
      level:2
      predicates: [
        {
          op: EQ
          field: abc,
          id:3.1
          level: 3
        }
      ]
    }]
  }]
}]
```

what I want is:

```
[{
  op:AND

  predicates: [{
    op: EQ
    field: abc,

  }, {
    op "OR"

    predicates: [{
      op: NEQ

      field: 12312
    },
    {
      op: AND

      predicates: [
        {
          op: EQ
          field: abc,

        }
      ]
    }]
  }]
}]
```

compared with the old (input) object array, we can see that all key and value wiht "id" and "level" are filtered

Why do I need this?

because the old (input) object is a dynamic object array, it is not alway the same structure as the example. so that is also difficult to write a recursion method.

so I wannt to need a better solution in typescript

Comment: Please consider editing the code to constitute a [mcve] so that someone can drop it into their IDE and demonstrate the issue.  As it stands I'd need to fix a bunch of typos to even get it to something I could work with.

Answer (score 0):

Hey question is not clear by below statement

> it is not alway the same structure as the example. so that is also
>   difficult to write a recursion method.

what's your exact use case? and what you are trying to achieve here?

if you just want to utilize your collection of data than, you can convert it to Modal class using library like class-transformer, and than you can iterate threw collection of your class as per your requirement.

```
 import { plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';
 const data = plainToClass(Person, parsedData as Object[]); // parsed data is json or API response and Person is your Modal class
```

than you can perform any sets of list, filter and display operation on collection of modal class, where you can ignore unwanted property based on your use case.